# What causes the slow down in crawling from a laptop program?

Tags: c#, .net, web-crawler, sql-server-express

I have a project that I have managed to save from a server that was outsourced and managed to get most of it working on one of the laptops I have at home. It has OS Win 8.1r, VS 2017, SQL Server Express 2017, and I wrote the DLL I use in my app in C# .NET version 4.6.1.

I am currently every night at midnight manually running some stored procs that fill some stat tables due to no MS Agent existing in SQL Server Express, then runs an index maintenance proc that either REBUILDS or DEFRAGS the indexes plus rebuilds stats before I manually restart the BOT from a command prompt at just after midnight.

However I have noticed if I leave the laptop on for 3-5 days the time each run takes to get (on average), 40 races and 5-20 runners per race going through proxies gets slower and slower. I just rebooted now as last night it took from 1am to 11am to crawl, scan with regex to get info and save to the DB races and runners.

However if I look at the CreateDate times I store on every new race I can see a pattern..

Yesterday took 10 hours to do 40 races and runners,
Saturday took 4 hours to do 50 races and runners
Friday 3 hours 49 races
Thursday 5 hours 42 races
Wednesday 5 hours 32 races
Tuesday 1 hour 36 races

Obviously over time more and more races & runners are stored in the DB, so retrieval times from indexes, storage etc gets longer but after a reboot it is quick Harry, I just restarted it tonight, rebuild the indexes then let it go and its already done 7 races in 7 minutes.

Obviously I haven't got a server to put this on, the last attempt resulted in an old boss putting it on a French server that doesn't allow access to online betting sites and my BOT uses the Betfair API.

It runs on my laptop ok apart from
-the speed of getting all races and runners into the DB lengthens over time. The longer I leave it on the longer it takes, despite all the clean up operations I do nightly (Delete old log messages, locks, and rebuild stat tables before a reindex/defrag job).

-For some reason the logfile I output debug messages to for after the fact debugging e.g I look for SQL Errors, Connection Errors, Proxy Issues, RegEx errors and I output this through the console app I am using the DLL with at the moment to a logfile in C:\programdata\myproj\logfile.txt - it has permissions as it writes to the file however once the job is over if I try and open it up in my standard Editor - Editplus, it just opens up a blank document. If I open it in Notepad first I can see all the debug then I can copy n paste it to a blank Editplus document.

It never did this before on my Work PC, Permissions are okay, the file is being written to and I don't get any "permission denied" or other I/O errors when opening the logfile up, it's just empty if I don't open it in Notepad.

So I'd like to know what sort of actions are happening to slow this job down over time that a reboot fixes. I know the old saying we used to get from our techies when we had a bug or issue with our PCs at work "have you tried turning it on and off again" - which does for some reason fix so many issues.

I'd just like to know what sort of issues could be happening to slow it down over days that I could maybe automate a clean up job so it doesn't happen. I used to run the exact same code on my Work PC connected remotely to a server every day for months before forced to do reboots due to Windows Updates. So it never used to do it with my bad practice at work of leaving my PC on all the time.

Is the disk getting fragmented - and why wouldn't it require a disk defrag to solve it after rebooting.
The registry? What could get worse and worse over time that a reboot fixes.
Or is it the fact I am using MS SQL Express 2017 and there is some I/O issue with the files it writes to that slows down over time.

I would just like to be able to leave my laptop on with this BOT running at specific times during the day and not worry about it taking 11 hours to complete the first import job.

It is now 37 mins past, been running for 20 mins and it has imported 15 races and runners, about a quarter of the total, so should be finished in about an hours time tonight, and I have JUST re-started my laptop, nothing else, and it has speeded it up from 10 hours yesterday night?

What could be slowing it down lover time, and can I fix it at all?

Comment: Take a step back, profile your application

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do, the only difference is the code is being run on my laptop with MS SQL Express and manually from a console at midnight, rather than on a server as a Windows Service. All the stats, index rebuilds etc were automated when on the server, yet the crawling was still done from my office PC. All I can see is the time stamps in my log file when I finally copy n paste from notepad into Editplus (why?), around calls to stored procs - save_race save_runner etc getting longer and longer. A reboot solves everything. This nights job is already complete. 10 hours yesterday.

Comment: If i am understanding your problem correctly, Have you profiled your sql server? do you know what queries are taking the most time. when you run those queries separately and profile them what happens, what does the query plan say.

Comment: Yes I know which queries take the most time I have built an extensive proc that shows me what processes are using most logical disk space, missing indexes, indexes not being used so causing time waste being updated, and other DMV related info. All the CUD from CRUD is done in Stored Procs, only a few adHoc queries are run as selects and they are indexed anyway. The same code, same processes and same files are open every time at night. It just gets slower the longer I leave the laptop on. 10 hours yesterday, not changed anything, rebooted, 34 races + runners all imported in 1hr 14mins ??? Why

Comment: I'd recommend you checking to see what the ram usage and disk usage is at. You didn't specify the hardware you were running this on. Does your laptop have an ssd? Keep an eye on what the task manager says in terms of performance. Regardless, you can build a mini ITX server for like $400, and it would be a beast at things like this.

Comment: Well im just running it now for results, the BOT.exe is using 3% CPU, 0.1Mbps Disk, 19.9 MB Memory and 0.1% Network, SQL Server WIndows 64 is using 478MBps, 0.4% CPU and 0.1MBps Disk. I can use other apps, browsers and email etc ok. I will have to check the stats when it is running slow. What I don't know is what is causing it to run slow. I would love to have my own server but I am now on the sick so money is tight which is why I am using a 64bit Windows 8.1 HP laptop with 8GB RAM, 913GB disk space, so round up.. Nothing changes on the PC from day to day, same actions are run. Just slows down

Comment: Tonight despite rebooting before last nights run seems to be a slow one. Nothing has been done differently. I just added 2 new indexes from a missing index DMV proc to see if that would help. looking at Task Manager SQL Server Windows NT 64 Bit is using 37% of 56% total CPU, 89% memory usage, SQL is using 451MB, also 43% 100% DISK, SQL using up to 76MBps, apart from network usage which I thought would be the most due to it being a crawler, if I order any column by process using the most SQL Win NT 64 Bit is at the top of the list, why now? What can I TSQL to find if its an SQL issue, e.g locks

Comment: Its now been an hour and only done 6 races and runners. This time yesterday it had completed the job. I might reboot. However just rebooting cannot be the permanent solution to this issue and I have no idea what a reboot is doing to solve this issue of slow SQL Server usage. It is like the writing to the logfiles or something SQL has to do gets harder the longer the service runs for. The crawling and all other actions, regex pattern matching and extraction is all quick as flash harry. It seems to be a slow down issue with SQL Server itself. Does anyone have any DMV based code that would help?

Comment: Ive rebooted and re-opened everthing I had open before and re-started it. It has now done 25 races and runners, with 17 having been done since the restart at 1:47 AM - So taking about 2/3 minutes to scrape, run regex, save a main record then up to 20 sub records Task Manager > After reboot
CPU 30% - SQL using most of it
Memmory 68% - SQL using 1,523.5MB
DISK 2% - SQL using 1.8%
Network - 0%

Comment: I've just rebooted but in MS Studio it keeps freezing as I run SELECTS with (nolock) to see how many records have been inserted etc. DISK is running at 100% with SQL Server 64 Bit running at 4.5MB/s. Memory is 89% but SQL using 2,489.3MB - 2GB, I guess its using VM on the disk which is why that is so high. Nothing new, no new code, just rebooted it and started the job with Task Manager open. Just not sure why it is now using so much memory up. Wish Express had an activity monitor, however everything is sequential so should not be any blocking/lock issues...

Comment: Had to stop the job as it was using all the memory and for some reason MS SQL Studio kept freezing. Noticed in the log file on saving items I was getting this error (timeout), prob due to MS SQL Error: Connection Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed while attempting to consume the pre-login handshake acknowledgement.  This could be because the pre-login handshake failed or the server was unable to respond back in time.  The duration spent while attempting to connect to this server was - [Pre-Login] initialization=19600; handshake=0;
Trying CCleaner, emptying temp files etc.

Comment: And also wondering if somehow the scraper itself is leaving files behind when it crawls e.g if it crawls pages on the web would or wouldn't that cause the HTML file to be loaded up in Windows/temp like a normal browser file. I am thinking something is growing over time, like temp files, or SQL logs or limits on SQL Express as indexes grow or something that means the more times I run it the slower it gets. No new code, no new files. So scratching head to why MS SQL is killing my machine CPU/RAM/DISK disk swaps etc. Going to try running it again

Comment: How big are the SELECTs you tried? Sometimes they take long to select 1mln records. Did you try full MSSQL reinstallation? Does the problem happen when you run other apps with this MSSQL server (ex. build some simple app that inserts 1mln random numbers to table and selects only even numbers, see if it works smoothly)?

Comment: 2 days after a reboot last night it took 1hr 34 mins to insert 49 races + X no of runner records.  Just when SQL runs slow so do all the queries. The SELECTS send to the SQL are small selects otherwise I just put them a in proc and call a short name EXEC dbo.usp_net_save_nonrunner @RunnerPK=10023; etc, Which Selects are you talking about as in tried? - the procs running the process or the DMV procs to try and find out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Something to keep in mind..

MS SQL Server, once it obtains memory it does not release it. Unless you have restricted how much it can claim, you may be running out of memory.

Comment: Do you have Anti-virus software running on your laptop? That can kill even server performance, so it is likely a culprit.